# Which should I use between cmd and the Python interpreter?

Tags: python

I have created a memo.py file in the 'C: / Python' directory using the Pycharm program.

```
# C:/Python/memo.py 
import sys
option = sys.argv[1]
memo = sys.argv[2]
print(option)
print(memo)
```

Where do I enter the content?

```
C:\Python>python memo.py -a "Life is too short"
```

cmd or Python interpreter or pycharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to pass command line arguments you can run it with cmd, but you should be in the folder where file exists. Also you have to make sure python is installed it there.

You can call it like this

```
python memo.py  "Life is too short" "one more argument"
```

Because you are program expect here for two arguments. or else you can try like :

```
python memo.py  Life is
```

where this will consider the word after space like second argument

The o/p for above will be like :

```
Life is too short
one more argument
```

second :

```
Life
is
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code using command line as Vikas suggested. If you really want to run the code using Pycharm, go to Run-->Edit configurations in Pycharm. Then in the "Script parameters" option write your arguments in double quotes separated by space and write -s in the "Interpreter" option. Then save the configuration and simply run the code using Run-->Run option